# Optimize min-max and groupby query for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have an input dataframe that looks like this:

```
  col0  col1 name
0   g0   100   n1
1   g0   120   n1
2   g1    40   n3
3   g1    30   n4
4   g2    10   n5
5   g2   100   n5
6   g2   250   n5
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe (or the same, it doesn't matter) where `col1` and `col2` contains respectively the minimum and maximum value for each tuple `(col0, name)`. I am able to perform this with the following snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col0': ["g0", "g0", "g1", "g1", "g2", "g2", "g2"], 'col1': [100, 120, 40, 30, 10, 100, 250], 'name': ["n1", "n1", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n5", "n5"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df_res = pd.DataFrame()

names = df["name"].unique()

for name in names:
    literals = df[df["name"] == name]["col0"].unique()

    for literal in literals:
        min_val = df[(df["name"] == name) &
                     (df["col0"] == literal)]["col1"].min()
        max_val = df[(df["name"] == name) &
                     (df["col0"] == literal)]["col1"].min()

        elem = {"col0": literal, "col1": min_val, "col2": max_val,
                "name": name}

        df_res = df_res.append(elem, ignore_index=True)
```

Which gives the desired output stored on `df_res`, which is as follows:

```
  col0   col1   col2 name
0   g0  100.0  100.0   n1
1   g1   40.0   40.0   n3
2   g1   30.0   30.0   n4
3   g2   10.0   10.0   n5
```

The thing is that I have to make this transformation with a dataframe with 95K registers and my approach is extremely slow (it takes several minutes no finish).

Therefore, my question is: is there any way to optimize this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.agg` and pass `min` and `max` to get the desired columns. To set custom names to aggregate columns, you can use named aggregation where you name the min column `col1` and max column `col2`:

```py
out = df.groupby(['col0','name'], as_index=False).agg(col1=('col1','min'), col2=('col1','max'))
```

The same code in another way:

```py
out = df.groupby(['col0','name'])['col1'].agg(['min','max']).set_axis(['col1','col2'], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
  col0 name  col1  col2
0   g0   n1   100   120
1   g1   n3    40    40
2   g1   n4    30    30
3   g2   n5    10   250
```